# Edit existing object and add new dependent object in rails 3 (Nested Forms)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Usually I just use something similar to 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Now i have an existing User which i am trying to add **new** cars and annimals. The User has_many cars and annimals and accepts_nested_attributes_for cars and annimals

If i do

```
= form_for(@user) do |f|
  = f.fields_for @user.cars.build do |c|
```

I get error:

> unknown attribute: car

And if i do

```
= form_for(@user) do |f|
  = f.fields_for :cars do |c|
```

I get a list of all existing cars for that user (when I want to make a new one)

Thannks!

ps: i guess i should add, i'm using simple_form_for and simple_fields_for, it might be a bug with that...

Comment: Do you have accepts_nested_attributes_for in the User model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deep inside the [rails api](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.4/) I found:

> It’s also possible to specify the instance to be used:

```
  <%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
    ...
    <% @person.projects.each do |project| %>
      <% if project.active? %>
        <%= person_form.fields_for :projects, project do |project_fields| %>
          Name: <%= project_fields.text_field :name %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

So in my case, i guess the syntax would be

```
= form_for(@user) do |f|
  = f.fields_for :cars, @user.cars.build do |c|
```